# Where should I ask about GitHub's history?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I am not asking about a programming question (rather, a history question), but said question concerns a programming website: GitHub. Where shall I post such question? The question I seek a locus for to post follows.

> The github.com website appears to have been created in October of 2007 according to multiple sources [see the full post below for all sources], yet exists [commits purportedly dated to 1987](https://github.com/jaseemabid/mit-scheme/commit/71f986024938276675a591f69269a49dd91ec6ed). What gives?

I have researched much, alas to no avail. [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) appeals to the programming aspect of this question, but it does not appear to be a "popular" place for history questions. On the other hand, History Beta has both "good" computer-related questions ([example here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50522/how-did-the-email-client-industry-develop)) and "bad" computer related questions ([example here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/how-were-the-first-computers-on-the-internet-connected)). My own untrained eye is blind to whether my question would be condemned as "bad" or praised as "good" on History Beta. Thus I ask which of any Stack Exchange sites welcomes and best suits my inquiry?

Below inheres a continuation of the full question started previously. Answer it not, as I merely seek to find where to post it, not a solution to it: the answer I seek surely is off-topic and would taint Meta Stack Exchange.

> The github.com website appears to have been created in October of 2007 according to multiple sources such as [Medium](https://medium.com/@smhatre59/the-untold-story-of-github-132840f72f56#0092), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_GitHub), and [Startlin](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409191635/http://www.startlin.es/timelines/github/). Yea, [Github itself claims](https://github.com/about) `October 2007: First commit`. Yet exists [commits purportedly dated to 1987](https://github.com/jaseemabid/mit-scheme/commit/71f986024938276675a591f69269a49dd91ec6ed)! What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not every question has a place on the Stack Exchange network. However, questions can often be rephrased to fit the scope of a particular site.

For example, questions about the use of GitHub the web site might be a good fit for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- Can GitHub handle commits that are older than GitHub?
- What does the commit date on GitHub mean – is it the date when the commit was pushed to GitHub?
- Can the date of a commit on GitHub be trusted?

On the other hand, questions about using the Git tool itself would be on topic on Stack Overflow:

- How can I backdate a Git commit?
- How can a newer Git commit be the parent of an older commit?
- How can I import an old version control repository into Git?

(See also: [Where does my Git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6311/))

Often, the trick for topicality to rephrase your question from a matter of *curiosity* to a concrete real-world *problem* that you are trying to solve. Unfortunately, already knowing the answer makes this a lot easier. But asking whether your understanding of some concept is correct can also help. In your case, your question doesn't really seem to be about the history of the world but about how Git and GitHub handle commit metadata.  I.e. you could ask:

> As far as I know, the date of a GitHub commit shows when the commit was created. But how could this commit be created in 198x when GitHub was only founded in 200y?

That is clearly not a history question, but more about the use of Git/GitHub as tools. As such it might just fit within the scope of Stack Overflow.